# How to use DateTimeFormatter of java.time package in JDK 1.8?

Tags: java-8, java-time, java.time.instant

How to use `DateTimeFormatter` of  `java.time` package in JDK 1.8?

When I use `LocalDate` I've got a Noclassdeffounderror.

I changed my project from JDK 1.7 to 1.8.

Is there any jar file to be added?

Comment: Ideally you should have posted your code.

Answer (score 0):

The java.time classes are native in JDK 8, you don't need to add any other jar.

Probably there's a problem in your IDE configuration or somewhere else. But without more details, we can only guess

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ravindra is wrong. You can use a LocalDate with a DateTimeFormatter, as soon as the formatter has only date related fields - like the built-in formatters DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE and ISO_LOCAL_DATE

The answer by Sgustu makes more sense. Perhaps you could try to rebuild your project or double check your JVM configuration